# »So wären/wäre es Träume nur gewesen?«

Tags: grammatical-number, expletiva

I saw a poster with this text:

> So wären es Träume nur gewesen?

The subject seems to be *es,* not *Träume.* Why is the Konjunktiv *wären* plural? I’d write:

> So **wäre** es Träume nur gewesen?

Comment: It's from "[Don Carlos](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/3338/3)" it's ancient German. The Konjunktiv is nowadays used in indirect speech to disassociate from a message. To Topic: You have to know the context - always in German, the context is important, in Don Carlos:`Carlos: "Du sprichst von **Zeiten**, die vergangen sind.
**Auch mir hat einst von einem Carl geträumt[...]
– O, der Einfall
War kindisch, aber göttlich schön!** Vorbei
Sind **diese Träume**." – Marquis:"Träume, Prinz? – So wären
**Es** Träume nur gewesen?"` **es** for **Zeiten** & **former ideals and actions** of Carlos.

Comment: so "sie" for plural of "es" is not applicable. Sorry the first source was in ancient font. I've read it again and realized my first answer was wrong.

Answer (score 10):

Finally I can answer again:

> So wären es Träume nur gewesen?

It is a quotation from Schillers "[Don Carlos](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/3338/3)" in ancient German (follow the link for the passage).

The "Konjunktiv" is nowadays used in indirect speech to disassociate from a message (like the anchorman from the news).

**To Topic**: You have to know the context -- always in German, the context is important.
The passage from Schillers Don Carlos:

> *Carlos*: "Du sprichst von **Zeiten**, die vergangen sind. **Auch mir
> hat einst von einem Carl geträumt [...] – O, der Einfall War kindisch,
> aber göttlich schön!** Vorbei Sind **diese Träume**." –
>
> *Marquis*:"Träume, Prinz? – So wären **Es** Träume nur gewesen?"

**Es** for **Zeiten & former ideals and actions** of Carlos.

---

From [Schiller's sämmtliche Werke in Einem Bande, Cotta 1834, p 249.](http://books.google.com/books/about/Schillers_s%C3%A4mmtliche_Werke.html?id=5-IIAAAAQAAJ) the passage in an ancient font:

[image: copy]

Answer (score 9):

The "real" subject in this sentence is *"die Träume*". The pronoun "es" is just a "dummy" word. It's easier to understand if you simplify the sentence and change the word order:

> Die Träume sind es.

This structure is called *"Prädikatsnominativ"*, *"Gleichsetzungsnominativ"* or *"Nominativobjekt"* in German grammar. You can only use it with following verbs:

- sein
- werden
- heißen
- scheinen (zu sein)
- bleiben
- gelten (als)
- (sich) fühlen (als)
- (sich) dünken (als)
- (sich) erweisen (als)
- (sich) entpuppen (als)
- sich glauben (als)